# Query group by pair of column result

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently my dataset consist of 4 columns, `id`, `status`, `user_id`, `created_date`

so after a while the data can be like this

```
(1, 'LOGIN', '2019-07-16 07:06:55', 'Bob')
(2, 'LOGOUT', '2019-07-16 07:29:13', 'Bob')
(3, 'LOGIN', '2019-07-16 07:30:31', 'Bob')
(4, 'LOGOUT', '2019-07-16 07:49:50', 'Bob')
(5, 'LOGIN', '2019-07-16 08:05:55', 'Tom')
(6, 'LOGOUT', '2019-07-16 08:15:13', 'Tom')
(7, 'LOGIN', '2019-07-16 09:13:55', 'John')
(8, 'LOGOUT', '2019-07-16 09:20:13', 'John')
```

I am trying to make it like this

```
(1, '2019-07-16 07:06:55', '2019-07-16 07:29:13', 'Bob', 22.5800)
(2, '2019-07-16 07:30:31', '2019-07-16 07:49:50', 'Bob', 19.5800)
(3, '2019-07-16 08:05:55', '2019-07-16 08:15:13', 'Tom', 9.5800)
(4, '2019-07-16 09:13:55', '2019-07-16 09:20:13', 'John', 6.5800)
```

So this is the query that I came up with so far

```
SELECT
  max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END)               AS login_date,
  CASE WHEN max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END) < max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END)
    THEN max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
      THEN A.action_date END)
  ELSE max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END) END           AS logout_date,
  A.full_name,
  CASE WHEN timestamp(max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END)) < timestamp(max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END)) OR max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
    THEN A.action_date END) IS NULL
    THEN 0
  ELSE
    (timestamp(max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
      THEN A.action_date END)) - timestamp(max(CASE WHEN action = 'LOGOUT'
      THEN A.action_date END))) / 100 END AS session_time
FROM (
       SELECT
         timestamp(created_date) AS action_date,
         name as full_name,
         status as action
       FROM `training_ground`.session
       WHERE status = 'LOGIN' OR status = 'LOGOUT'
       GROUP BY action, cast(action_date AS DATE), name
       ORDER BY action_date DESC) AS A
GROUP BY A.full_name
ORDER BY A.action_date DESC;
```

I have no idea how to differentiate first login-logout to the second login-logout session, with this query, I am only getting

```
(1, '2019-07-16 07:06:55', '2019-07-16 07:29:13', 'Bob', 22.5800)
(2, '2019-07-16 08:05:55', '2019-07-16 08:15:13', 'Tom', 9.5800)
(3, '2019-07-16 09:13:55', '2019-07-16 09:20:13', 'John', 6.5800)
```

Is there a way to group login-logout as a set, so that I can differentiate every single pair of login-logout sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a left join and then subtract the 2 dates:

```
select 
  t.id, 
  t.action_date login_date, tt.action_date logout_date,
  t.user_id,
  (tt.action_date - t.action_date) / 100 session_time
from (
  select * from session where status = 'LOGIN'  
) t left join (
  select * from session where status = 'LOGOUT'    
) tt on tt.user_id = t.user_id and 
  tt.action_date = (
    select min(action_date) from session
    where status = 'LOGOUT' and user_id = t.user_id and action_date > t.action_date
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6z8UT466UMuKupSLhbrYbp/2).
Results:

```
| id  | login_date          | user_id | logout_date         | session_time |
| --- | ------------------- | ------- | ------------------- | ------------ |
| 1   | 2019-07-16 07:06:55 | Bob     | 2019-07-16 07:29:13 | 22.58        |
| 3   | 2019-07-16 07:30:31 | Bob     | 2019-07-16 07:49:50 | 19.19        |
| 5   | 2019-07-16 08:05:55 | Tom     | 2019-07-16 08:15:13 | 9.58         |
| 7   | 2019-07-16 09:13:55 | John    | 2019-07-16 09:20:13 | 6.58         |
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i didnt quite think about using left join, was too focused on grouping them together.

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation over provided inputs.
i have data set like:

```
select id, stat[status],dater[Date], name[Name] from tablelogin
```

[image]
Data Extraction:

```
Select t1.id, t1.dater[login], t2.dater[logout], t1.name[name], datediff(day,t1.dater, t2.dater)[days] from tablelogin t1, tablelogin t2 where t1.name=t2.name and t2.id>t1.id and t2.stat='logout'
```

[image]

you need to work on logic and control, when records grows the above query may produce different results.

Comment: i do not work with mysql, the query and result is from sql server, believing sql is almost same every where may be some implementation differs. you need to get logic if works for you.

Comment: You are incorrect there are many (significant) differences between sql dialects